# Python Subclasses Seemingly Editing Eachother

Tags: python, class, subclass

While working to create a basic text-adventure in the form of "Colossal Cave Adventure", "Zork", etc., I've encountered an issue with my Zombie and Skeleton classes seemingly editing each other.

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,strength,defense,armor=False,weapon=Fist(),actions=["Attack","Block"]):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = self.maxhp = hp
        self.strength = strength
        self.default_defense = self.defense = defense
        self.armor = armor
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.initiative = 0
        self.actions = actions

    def attack(self,target):
        #An attack action
    def block(self):
        #A block action
    def update(self):
        #Updating the entity

class Zombie(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__(self,"Zombie",random.randint(13,20),4,5,Leather())
        print self.actions    #Printing the actions in order to try to fix this issue
        self.actions.remove("Block")
        print self.actions    #Printing the actions in order to try to fix this issue

class Skeleton(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__(self,"Skeleton",random.randint(16,23),6,5,False,Bow(999))
        print self.actions    #Printing the actions in order to try to fix this issue
        self.actions.remove("Block")
        print self.actions    #Printing the actions in order to try to fix this issue

monsters = [Zombie(),Skeleton()]
```

When the code is run, it returns

```
['Attack','Block']
['Attack']
['Attack']
#Error message
```

The error says that `'Block'` isn't in the Skeleton's `self.actions` to remove, but as far as my understanding goes, `'Block'` should be in there when `Entity.__init__` is called. If I switch `Zombie()` and `Skeleton()` in `monsters`, the problem still happens, so the problem seems to be that the first subclass is removing the entry from both subclasses.

I'm new to subclasses, so it's very likely that the issue is in my limited understanding of how they work. Is this the intended behavior? If so, how would I get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm out of votes, but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Very helpful. I appreciate being able to understand the problem than just simply fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default argument for `__init__` is only evaluted once.
So if you don't give something else for `actions` every instance of `Entity` will reference the exact same list. And when you remove from that list in one instance the list in the other instances is also modified.

To prevent this from happening try this:

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, ... actions=None, ...):
    ...
    if actions is None:
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Block"]
    else:
        self.actions = actions
```

Then the `actions` list is created for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a list as the default argument to `actions` in the `__init__` of `Entity`.

Each of your subclasses holds a reference to the original list `["Attack", "Block"]`. Whenever you modify it, the original list is updated, which is probably not what you were expecting.

To avoid that sort of error use immutable types as default arguments, e.g. `tuple` instead of `list`.